# Counting Down With Date Object

Tags: javascript, date

so I was just wondering what the best way to countdown using the date object would be here. I'm building a Pomodoro Timer and right now I'm setting the minutes for breaks and working periods with the settings object.

[Timer Code Here](https://gist.github.com/JelaniThompson/d131bce20dba91bda829)

I planned to multiply the values in the object by the minutes variable to get the amount of minutes there are, but how would I go about actually counting down? (this goes for the seconds variable as well).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You may create a `Date` object to save the start date/time, then use `setInterval` to regularly compare it with the current date/time. Here is some example code:

```
var startTime, timer;

function startCountdown() {
    startTime = new Date();
    timer = setInterval(updateElapsedTime, 1000);
}

function stopCountdown() {
    clearInterval(timer);
}

var updateElapsedTime = function() {

    var now = new Date();
    var seconds_elapsed = (now.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000;

    /* Do your things here */

}
```